# Chrome - Save to PDF function use in a website

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, pdf

Chrome allows users to hit Ctrl + P and choose 'Save to PDF'.

Is it possible to have this function through an html button?

I want the user to just hit a button and go directly to the Save as PDF prompt ( where the file name is set by PHP and not automatically by Chrome ). So the user basically just hits the button and clicks on Save on the prompt window.

Is this possible?
Can I skip the previous steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your user can hit ctrl+P in the browse, the PHP process that generated the page (on server) is already closed.

Besides the fact that PHP exerts no direct control over browsers. It just sends them information in the form of HTML/CSS and important in this case **JavaScript**.

With JavaScript you could trigger the normal print behaviour of the browser but you would have no control over it.

Another approach could be to generate the PDF on server and send it as a file to the browser. In which case the browser will either ask the user if he wants to open it or it will ask the user if he wants to download it.

I've personally used [fPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to customise the PDF invoices of various open source e-commerce software. Like for example [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/en/download).

All you really need to do is download the library from (fPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), but seeing it in action and being able to change/adapt a working version might help you so you could look for the PDF invoice in a fresh the PrestaShop install inside the folder **classes** the file name is PDF.php .

Comment: That approach is interesting, any links/sources that might help?

Comment: The one about creating PDF files on server?

Comment: Yes, any sources on that would be very helpful. This way I can generate the PDFs server-side and prompt the user to download them, just like you said. Fair solution to my problem.

Comment: Well I must warn you that the ones I've used (like [fPDF])(http://www.fpdf.org/) have a bit of a learning curve. And the most annoying thing about them is that you're setting up the server push a PDF document to the browser, that means that using **echo**/**var_dump** to debug  is pretty much a pain.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Well, I guess I'll have to take it slow and steady from now on then.

Comment: DOMPDF might be a bit easier to get the hang of. Because it accepts HTML/CSS (but not just any HTML/CSS it has it's own restrictions AFAIK).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it's not possible.

But, you can give the user the choice to download a HTML file output as a PDF file. There are a few libraries around, Prince is the best but expensive, so check out [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record, do you know why it's not possible?

Comment: DOMDocument is a XML library. There are some libraries that let you input XML/HTML code and they build the PDF file for you.

Comment: @hermann Because the browser API only provides `window.print()`, which doesn't take any options.

Comment: Most often I've seen fPDF or similar libraries being used. They allow you to build the PDF but it's work-flow is similar to PostScript (the language from which PDF files are generated).

Comment: @yms PDFs are compiled postscript with embedded images and extra features (file self destruct, passwords, no-printing etc.). And varios (current) Linux implementations use PostScript engines as a basis for generating PDF files. Also notable info is the fact that Adobe needed a suit of tools called GhostScript as a common resource for PDF files and PostScript files. There are PHP libraries that convert PostScript to PDF (no config / coding necessary).

Comment: @yms [PDF Technical foundations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Technical_foundations) so basically PDF is reduced PostScript + embedded data.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Your assumptions are not correct. GhostScript is an open source implementation of a Postscript language interpreter (it started as that, it is a lot more currently), Ghostscript **it is not** related to Adobe, and certainly Adobe does not need GhostScript in any way.

Comment: @yms I might be wrong about GhostScript I haven't read anything on it, I had a recollection of having to install GostScript along with some Adobe tools, but I haven't used Windows in 4 years, memory must be playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 0):

I lost several hours trying to make conversion to pdf on the server with no luck because my view contains some jquery functions that do the main rendering. I thought of providing a button to save as pdf using the browser but then opted to using javascript on the client side to do the rendering to pdf. This may not be the optimal solution in certain cases but looked the most sensible one in my case.

there are many libraries I just started using html2pdf.js and it is working fine so far.